# Centering text on a button

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, button, centering

I have created two buttons where the .Text property contains characters that I want to center, but I can't get it to work properly. Currently the buttons look like this:

[image]

And the code looks like this:

```
btnUp.Text = "▲";
btnDown.Text = "▼";
btnUp.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
btnDown.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
```

But what I really want is the Buttons' texts to be centered, so the arrows will be exactly in the middle of the controls. How would I achieve this?

A closer look to show why I am not happy:

[image]

**Thanks to Thomas Mondel's solution**
Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: u mean the arrow marks in the buttons should be centered ? the arrows look centered to me, just in case try putting the align codes below the btnup.text fields

Comment: The arrows look very much centered ..

Comment: Added another picture to show why I don't consider it centered

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can try to set the `UseCompatibleTextRendering` property on the buttons to `True`. It did the trick for me.

[image: UseCompatibleTextRendering]

Hope this helps.

Comment: This also helped me for centering vertically my text when the button flatStyle is set to flat.